# Facebook page-tab app - doesnt send 'signed_request' to canvas url, but works okay with secure canvas url

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, https

I have a Facebook Page-Tab App. I've specified both Canvas URL and Secure Canvas URL from the app settings page.

If the user is logged in on facebook on https, the iframe loads the right secure canvas and everything works fine.

If the user is logged in on facebook on http, the iframe loads the non secure canvas but it is not passing the signed_request parameter. I need it to detect if the user liked the page or not.

I looked around and I found similar problems but not really solutions. Any Hints?

Thanks